# How do I find all lines with more than N occurences of a character using Vim

Tags: vim, search, regex

I'm trying to located all lines in a file where the `|` (pipe) character occurs more than 21 times. The `|` character is a field delimiter, so there is no specific number of characters that may fall between `|` instances. Is there an easy way to do this in Vim?

NOTE: I am using gVim on a Windows machine, so I won't be able to use any *nix specific tricks.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regexp to find such lines with the normal search function:

```
/\v(\|[^|]*){21,}
```

The `\v` makes sure the regexp works regardless of the value of the `magic` option (it makes all non-alphanumeric characters (except underscore) special; I also use it here to avoid having to put backslashes before the `(`, `)`, `{`, and `}`).

If you want to see all such lines at once, then you can combine it with the `:g` command:

```
:g/\v(\|[^|]*){21,}/p
```

Incidentally, this type of command (from the *ex* predecessor to *vi*) is the origin for the name of the `grep` tool (`g/re/p`: re short for regexp).

---

If your source data is “pipe delimited”, then you should probably check to see if any of the values have embedded pipe characters (maybe done by escaping (e.g. prefixed with a backslash), doubling, or quoting). The regexp method above can be extended to cover most escaping and doubling methods, but parsing quoted values usually requires power expressive power than most regexp languages can offer.

Comment: The file is pipe delimited and the problem is that there are some non-escaped pipe characters found in some fields that should not be there (causing an issue with a program that is based on the assumption that there are no pipe characters unless they are being used as a delimiter). I wanted to go through the file to get an idea of how many lines were "illegal". Anyway, your answered worked great. Thanks for the help.